# Allowing table cell to be pressed only once

Tags: ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

In my iOS app I have come across a problem with being able to select a table cell multiple times before some action is completed.

My situation is that I have the user type a value in and then hit submit. While trying to fully test my code I have noticed that submit can be pressed multiple times before my activity indicator shows. This results in multiple submissions.

How would I fix this for a table? Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you could disable user interaction for the entire view (including all UITableViewCells):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

Then, wherever you're handling your operation's completion, re-enable the view:

```
-(void)yourOperationIsFinished{
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yes I saw this method but for some reason this way of using it didn't occur to me. Thanks, that works great.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag that indicates if the cell has been selected at least once, which is initially `NO`. As soon as a table view cell is selected, the method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called. In this method, you could set a flag to `YES`.
If you implement also the method `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, which is called before `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you could return either the submitted `indexPath`, as long as your flag is `NO`, or `nil` after the first call to `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. In this case, the cell will no longer be selected.